# How to restrict perl debugging in a given set of modules or lib path?

Tags: perl, debugging

When debugging a perl program with `perl -d`, How can I restrict it to step in only given set of modules or a path to `lib` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DB::cmd_b_sub`](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.26.1/lib/perl5db.pl#L5131) or [`DB::break_subroutine`](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.26.1/lib/perl5db.pl#L5092) functions set a breakpoint at the start of an arbitrary function. You can walk the stash to find the set of arguments to pass to this function. For example,

```
sub add_breakpoints_for_module {
    my $module = shift;
    return unless $INC{"perl5db.pl"};    # i.e., unless debugger is on
    no strict 'refs';
    for my $sub (eval "values %" . $module . "::") {
        if (defined &$sub) {          # if the symbol is valid sub name
            DB::cmd_b_sub(substr($sub,1));   # add breakpoint
        }
    }
}
```

This code should be run after the relevant modules have been loaded.

---

And here's how to use this idea as a separate library. Save this code to `Devel/ModuleBreaker.pm` somewhere on your `@INC` path and invoke the debugger as

```
perl -d:ModuleBreaker=Some::Module,Some::Other::Module script_to_debug.pl args
```

.

```
# Devel/ModuleBreaker.pm - automatically break in all subs in arbitrary modules
package Devel::ModuleBreaker;
sub import {
    my ($class,@modules) = @_;
    our @POSTPONE = @modules;
    require "perl5db.pl";
}
CHECK { # expect compile-time mods have been loaded before CHECK phase
    for my $module (our @POSTPONE) {
        no strict 'refs';
        for my $sub (eval "values %" . $module . "::") {
            defined &$sub && DB::cmd_b_sub(substr($sub,1));
        }
    }
}
1;
```

---

And here's a version that will break on subroutines that match arbitrary patterns (which should make it easier to break inside submodules). It takes advantage of the `%DB::sub` table, which has information about all loaded subroutines (including anonymous subs).

```
package Devel::SubBreaker;
# install as Devel/SubBreaker.pm on @INC
# usage:  perl -d:SubBreaker=pattern1,pattern2,... script_to_debug.pl args
sub import {
    my $class = shift;
    our @patterns = @_;
    require "perl5db.pl";
}
CHECK {
    foreach my $sub (keys %DB::sub) {
        foreach my $pattern (our @patterns) {
            $sub =~ $pattern and DB::cmd_b_sub($sub), last;
        }
    }
}
```